# Remove Duplicates From License Array

Tags: powershell

I'm having an issue removing duplicates from my array.

```
$DataSheet = Import-Csv C:\Temp\Groups.CSV
$LicenseData = @()

foreach ($Group in $DataSheet) {
    $GroupMembership = Get-ADGroupMember $Group.Name | Select SamAccountName
    foreach ($Member in $GroupMembership) {
        $LicenseInfo = "" | Select "ID","GroupName","EngineLicense","UserLicense"
        $LicenseInfo.ID = $Member.SamAccountName
        $LicenseInfo.GroupName = $Group.Name
        $LicenseInfo.EngineLicense = $Group.EngineLicense
        $LicenseInfo.UserLicense = $Group.UserLicense
        $LicenseData += $LicenseInfo
    }
}

$LicenseData | Sort-Object ID |
    Export-Csv C:\Temp\LicenseData.CSV -NoTypeInformation -Force
$EngineLicense = $LicenseData | Group -Property $EngineLicense |
                 ForEach {$_.Group | Sort-Object EngineLicense -Unique} |
                 Select EngineLicense, ID |
                 Sort-Object EngineLicense
$UserLicense   = $LicenseData | Group -Property $UserLicense |
                 ForEach {$_.Group | Sort-Object UserLicense -Unique} |
                 Select UserLicense, ID |
                 Sort-Object UserLicense
```

This is an example of what `$LicenseData` looks like

```
ID        GroupName EngineLicense UserLicense
--        --------- ------------- -----------
TestUser1 Group A   Mobile        Professional
TestUser1 Group B   ERQA          ERQA
TestUser1 Group B   ERQA          ERQA
TestUser2 Group A   Mobile        Professional
TestUser2 Group B   ERQA          ERQA
```

`$EngineLicense` looks like

```
EngineLicense ID
------------- --
ERQA          TestUser1
Mobile        TestUser1
```

What I'm trying to do is display each user's consumed licenses, but removing duplicate licenses for a user. Currently the `-Unique` is removing duplicate engine licenses.

Ideally this is what I envision it to look like. Note that is shows the licenses consumed for both users and removed the duplicate ERQA entry for TestUser1.

```
EngineLicense ID
------------- --
ERQA          TestUser1
Mobile        TestUser1
ERQA          TestUser2
Mobile        TestUser2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something the following should produce the desired result:

```
$LicenseData | Select-Object -Unique EngineLicense, ID |
    Sort-Object ID, EngineLicense
```